# How to describe a JsonNode property with Swagger annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am currently documenting my API requests, and I have encountered an issue with a request that includes a JsonNode property. I have been attempting to use the @Schema annotation to add a description to this particular field, but unfortunately, it does not seem to be functioning as expected, the description is not appearing on Swagger. The @Schema annotation works properly for other fields in the request.

Example class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;


public class UserRequest {
     @Schema(name = "name", description = "Username", example = "Rafael")
     private String name;

     @Schema(name = "params", description = "Parameters XPTO")
     private JsonNode params;
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make the description visible for the JsonNode property in Swagger.